# bootstrap accordion collapse, jquery, js, bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I have some code which need to collapse on click. Currently always is open first panel. I want when click on link in some other panel to open that panel and close first panel. First panel need to be open only if i click on link in first panel. This is my code. Also when i add custom panel between two panels appear line. I have tried with this code.

```
   //jquery

   $("a").on('click',function(e){
          $ (this).addClass('collapse in');
       });

 //menu
<div class="container"><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close">
                            </span>Users</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary" ></span><a href="add.php">Users</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash text-success"></span><a href="user.php?all">View users</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th">
                            </span>Campaigns</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Orders</a> <span class="label label-success">$ 320</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Invoices</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Shipments</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Tex</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
                            </span>Statistics</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Change Password</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Something</a> <span class="label label-info">5</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Import/Export</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger"></span><a href="#" class="text-danger">
                                            Delete Account</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">
                            </span>Account</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span><a href="change_pass.php">Change password</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><a href="#">Notifications</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><a href="mcccp.php">View Acc</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--my custom panel-->
                    <?php 
                    if ($_SESSION["userStatus"] == "superadmin") {

                        echo '<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                  Adminn
                              </a>
                            </h4>
                          </div>
                          <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>
                                            <a href="admin.php">Admin Options</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                            <a href="admin2.php?all">Options</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>';

                        echo '<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                  Other panel
                              </a>
                            </h4>
                          </div>
                          <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                            <a href="mc.php">Create  Account</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                            <a href="mcv.php">View Accounts</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>';

                        echo '<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeven">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                  Other Panel 2
                              </a>
                            </h4>
                          </div>
                          <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                            <a href="vs.php">Create Account</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                            <a href="vsss.php">View Accounts</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <!--end custom panel-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a working example please?

Comment: I have tried with js fiddle to make something. https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=0VbmKyqHed

Answer (score 0):

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd; 
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion</h2>



<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <button class="accordion">Section2.1</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>
<h3><center>section2.1 content</center></h3>
 </p>
</div>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p><h2>section3</h2></p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

do you want something like these ?

Comment: No, when user click on, for example, section 2, all other panel needs to be closed, only clicked panel need to be open.

Comment: do you have any example for that @one_question

Comment: In short, first panel need to be open, when i first time enter into page and after user choose link in, for example, third panel this panel need to be open and all others need to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/714fymdq/

```js
var dynamicPanel1 = `<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                  Adminn
                              </a>
                            </h4>
                          </div>
                          <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>
                                            <a href="admin.php">Admin Options</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                            <a href="admin2.php?all">Options</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>`;
                        
var dynamicPanel2 = `<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                  Other panel
                              </a>
                            </h4>
                          </div>
                          <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                            <a href="mc.php">Create  Account</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                            <a href="mcv.php">View Accounts</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>`;

var dynamicPanel3 = `<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeven">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                  Other Panel 2
                              </a>
                            </h4>
                          </div>
                          <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                            <a href="vs.php">Create Account</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                            <a href="vsss.php">View Accounts</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>`
                        
$('#accordion').append(dynamicPanel1, dynamicPanel2, dynamicPanel3);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close">
                            </span>Users</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary" ></span><a href="add.php">Users</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash text-success"></span><a href="user.php?all">View users</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th">
                            </span>Campaigns</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Orders</a> <span class="label label-success">$ 320</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Invoices</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Shipments</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Tex</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
                            </span>Statistics</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Change Password</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Something</a> <span class="label label-info">5</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Import/Export</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger"></span><a href="#" class="text-danger">
                                            Delete Account</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">
                            </span>Account</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span><a href="change_pass.php">Change password</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><a href="#">Notifications</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><a href="mcccp.php">View Acc</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--my custom panel-->
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since I can't use php in **jsfiddle**, I have created the **last** **three panel dynamically** using `jQuery`.

You need to remove the **.in** class from the 1st panel.

You need to change the code to `php` from `jQuery`.

Comment: Yes, but when i click on link in some panel, for example, third panel, this panel need to be open then. When click on link in second panel, second panel is open and all others are closed and so on. If I remove in when click on link in panel all panels are closed.

Comment: @one_question ... that's what the code is doing... At a particular moment only 1 panel should be open (which panel user click), right???

Comment: @one_question . Doubt: **1)**Initially 1st Panel will be open, right? **2)**Once an user click on 4th panel, 1st Panel will be closed & 4th Panel will open up? **3)**Then user clicks on 2nd Panel, 4th will close & 2nd will open, right? This is what you are looking for???

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Yes, but when user click, for Campaigns panel and click on link Orders, browser will load Ordres page and panel Campaigns will be open.

Comment: Can you share your entire HTML structure in a fiddle? I'm bit confuse how you have structured it, because I believe accordion will be in once place of Web Page & your dynamic content will be in other parts of the page (that means there is no reloading of the page).

Comment: This page currently contain only accordion menu and of course html, body, head and link references to bootstrap, jquery. When i am on this page, first panel is open and shows links in first panel, and now when i click on second panel, this panel is opened and shows his links. Now when i click on some link in that second panel, i will normally go to this page and in this new page this second panel will be opened and shows his links.